# File.Exists returns true then filestream throws FileNotFoundException ONLY logged in console

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file-not-found

In my serialization class I have a method which deserializes an xml file with an instance of my `Settings` class. There is nothing else which should be touching the file, and the file should never be deleted by anything in my program.
This only happens during the application's startup routine (called in the `load` event of the main form).

```
if (!File.Exists("Settings.xml"))
{
    return new Settings();
}

XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
using (FileStream fS = new FileStream("Settings.xml", FileMode.Open)) //Exception thrown.
using (XmlReader xRead = XmlReader.Create(fS))
{
    return (Settings)xSerializer.Deserialize(xRead);
}
```

When my program reaches the first "using" statement (confirmed via breakpoints), Visual Studio adds the following two lines to the output window:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

It then successfully deserializes the settings file.
This is especially odd since I do not get any other notification of the error. I cannot figure out what is causing this and although it has no observable effects on the program I would rather not leave it with this exception being thrown as it may have other implications.

What is causing these exceptions?

Comment: Do you have any code running before the Initialize() method?  If not I usually find this type error occurs in Events when the code isn't checking for items that are null.  Event on forms are in the designer file which get called by Initialize().  So I would remove and event that get registered in teh designer file and move to the load file after the object get configured.  Open the designer.cs file and check for any +=.

Comment: This is common for the `XmlSerializer` to do. It happens to me as well. I researched this a while ago when I bumped into the same problem, but I'm afraid it's too long ago for me to have any references. It's not caused by your code but by Microsoft's. The exception is handled, which is why your code continues to work. There's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: @jdweng I followed the code through and no events were being triggered before the load event. As others are stating it appears that the issue is with some Microsoft code and it is properly handled. The designer code seems to be fine. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: I would comment out the event as a test to see if it is related to the events.   The add back until you find which is causing the issue.  Had issue similar to this years ago.  It had to do with the sequencing of startup code in the initialize and the load event.  I think the way I found it by adding exception handler until I found where the issue was located.  If you have any code with USING statements they block the exception messages so replace using with try/catch to get any exception messages that are occurring.

Comment: @jdweng Isn't a `using` statement compiled as a try/finally? This wouldn't make sense to block an exception.

Comment: May be, but the error messages aren't displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** If your code works, don't worry about it.

**Longer answer:** It's probably looking for another file that can't be found.

If you *really* want to know what is causing it, download and run [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). It'll show you what every process is doing. You can use this page to learn how to setup filters so you only see what your process is doing: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/appv/2008/01/24/process-monitor-hands-on-labs-and-examples/

Setup a couple filters, like "Process Name is [your exe file]" and "Result is not SUCCESS". Chances are, you'll see a failure to find some file that you don't even care about :)

Answer (score 1):

let me first say this, If your code works that means its not one of your file that is missing and its probably not related to your code.

I looked around and found that this error

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Can even happen when trying to load some standard.net class library as seen in this link since the error is happening in the mscorlib.dll which is a base class library :
https://forums.asp.net/t/2077697.aspx?+System+IO+FileNotFoundException+in+mscorlib+dll+when+loading+standard+net+class+library

So Its probably something that even if you find the file it wouldn't do much and would just take you a while to fix. So unless it causes some problem I would suggest to just overlook this and move on.